# Positioning images on multiple screen devices with custom view

Tags: android, view

I have a custom `View` class which displays a map with few flags located at some positions.
It should look like this :
[image: Map example, images taken from Google]
*(Images are taken from Google)*

I draw those flags with `Canvas`'s `drawBitmap` method.
Unfortunately it doesn't display the same exact position in different screen sizes.

[image]

I have tried using these :

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFile.getAbsolutePath(), opt);
```

But it will result exactly same images on all screens (will display a small image in large screen), which is not good.
So the image should be scaled too.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Just a guess. check if the flag has white background by default. If so you might have to use a different image with transparent background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this my self but you probably need to account for the density of the screen.

```
int multiplier = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

I.e this will return 0.75 for `LDPI`. Then you'll have to use the `MDPI` as a base line and account for the other types of displays with the multiplier.

E.g

```
int top = y * multiplier;
int left = x * multiplier;
```

If I'm totally wrong I'll delete this answer, but this was what came to my mind.